# SfDateRangePicker update to disable date when onSelectionChanged date

Tags: flutter

I use SfDateRangePicker I want to select only 5 days and than disable other date, I don't want to reload widget on day 5 because if I don't stand current month It will relaod to current month when I reload widget.

Comment: Can you include your current snippet

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to achieve that by associating a key to `SfDateRangePicker` so it rebuilds itself on each new selection/deselection. Use the `selectableDayPredicate` to enable/disable the dates accordingly.

Here's the result:

[image: Screenshot]

Here's the source for the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) above:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datepicker/datepicker.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _controller = DateRangePickerController();

  void _onSelectionChanged(DateRangePickerSelectionChangedArgs args) {
    print(_controller.selectedDates);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('DatePicker demo'),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: 0,
              height: 80,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Selected dates: ${_controller.selectedDates}'),
                  Text(
                      'Selected dates count: ${_controller.selectedDates?.length}'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              left: 0,
              top: 80,
              right: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              child: SfDateRangePicker(
                key: ValueKey(_controller.selectedDates?.length ?? 0),
                controller: _controller,
                selectableDayPredicate: (date) {
                  if (_controller.selectedDates == null) return true;

                  return _controller.selectedDates!.length < 5 ||
                      _controller.selectedDates!
                          .any((element) => element == date);
                },
                onSelectionChanged: _onSelectionChanged,
                selectionMode: DateRangePickerSelectionMode.multiple,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```